# How to cutomise the url sent with Meteor Accounts.ui forgetpassword

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm using **accounts.ui** for forget password

```
Accounts.forgotPassword({email: "test@test.com"}, function (e, r) {
    if (e) {
        console.log(e.reason);
    } else {
        // success
    }
});
```

When I send the email for forget password I simply get below email

[image]

**Can someone tell me how to simply change the url and send the token with the same token**

I tried using below code but that didn't work

**main.js(client)**

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  Accounts.resetPassword.text = function(user, url) {
    url = url.replace('#/', '/');
    console.log("url ==== ", url)
    return `Click this link to reset your password: ${url}`;
  }
});
```

Comment: What exactly means 'it didn't work?' do you use a Router on the ui? Does a route exists for the given custom url with a relating template?

Answer (score 1):

On the server side:

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.subject = function () {
  return "Forgot your password?";
};

Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.text = function (user, url) {
  return "Click this link to reset your password:\n\n" + url;
};
```

Read: https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-emailTemplates

Comment: Why do I have a -1? This is exactly how you solve the problem stated by the OP:
https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html

Answer (score 0):

To change the `resetPassword` url to a custom one you have to run below code on your server (inside of `/server/main.js` file).

```js
Accounts.urls.resetPassword = function (token) {
  return FlowRouter.url("/reset-password/:token/", { token });
};
```

In this case, I am using a FlowRouter to generate that URL but you could technically just return a template literal if you like.

If the above code is in the server `main.js` file and you run `Accounts.forgotPassword()` function on the frontend from a localhost, it would generate this link:

`http://localhost:3000/reset-password/C9cGfgaLEgGXbCVYJcCLnDYiRi3XJpmt2irLOOaKe56`